# Is there a way to escape pound character (#) in ColdFusion?

Tags: json, coldfusion

I have a function in a CFC file that takes a JSON string as an argument. The function then uses the deserialized data to execute an UPDATE query. In the the JSON string, one of the properties has the character `#` as part of the name. This character makes the code to break in ColdFusion because it is interpreted as a variable. Is there any way to make ColdFusion "escape" that character and consider it just a string? Remember that is part of JSON string.

Below is my function. It doesn't allow me to access `dnisObject` because of the `#` characters within the JSON string. If I delete those `#` from the JSON string it works fine. Those values have to be stored in a database with the `#`, so I can not just delete them completely.

```
<cffunction name="updateDnisHproduct" access="remote">
    <cfargument name = "lid" type = "numeric" required = "yes">
    <cfargument name = "updatedObj" type = "string" required="yes">


    <cfset dnisObject = DESERIALIZEJSON(arguments.updatedObj)/>

    <cfset test =[{"phone":"1001106672","lineType":"Outbound","label1":"Voicemail for line #54940","label4":"test","hcat":"18","freshStart":"0","phoneCode":"","hproduct":"3","checked":false},{"phone":"1001106672","lineType":"Outbound","label1":"Voicemail Line Box #58940","label4":"12","hcat":"54","freshStart":"0","phoneCode":"","hproduct":"12","checked":false}'>

    <cfset dnisObject = DESERIALIZEJSON(test)/>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Side note, be sure to `var/local` all of the function local variables or you can end up with weird (and difficult to reproduce) bugs, under certain conditions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same way you normally escape pound signs: double them. From the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/elements-of-cfml/special-characters.html):

> ...To include [pound signs] in a string, double the character; for
>   example, use `##` to represent a single `#` character.

Since the input is a string, just do a [Replace()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/replace.html) to substitute a single pound sign with two pound signs.

Comment: Is that a ColdFusion function Replace(), if so what is the full syntax for that function?

Comment: Did you look at the link above? It explains the function and syntax.

Comment: I see, I missed that. This is clear now. I will do the change to the code tomorrow and update here in the case for people who reads this later

Comment: If you think it will be helpful to someone else, feel free to post an "answer" with your working example.

Comment: @DoArNa Better yet, update your question with the solution code and mark this answer as the Accepted Answer so Leigh gets the rep points.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <cfset test = '[{"phone":"1001106672","lineType":"Outbound","label1":"Voicemail Line For Call Box #54940","label4":"test","hcats":"18","freshStart":"0","phoneCode":"","hproduct":"3","checked":false},{"phone":"1001106672","lineType":"Outbound","label1":"Voicemail Line For Call Box #54940","label4":"test","hcats":"54","freshStart":"0","phoneCode":"","hproduct":"--","checked":false}]'>

 <!--- Escaping # sign using replace function so it doesn't get confused with the variable sign in 
ColdFusionldFusion --->

<cfset test = Replace(test, "#", "##" "all")
<cfset dnisObject = DESERIALIZEJSON(test)/>
<cfdump var="#dnisObject#">
```

Comment: The pound signs need to be escaped in the function expression:  `Replace(test, "##", "####" "all")`.  (Also missing closing `>` after the 2nd `cfset`.)