# How do you output a Coldfusion variable within jquery script?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coldfusion, jquery-ui-slider

In coldfusion I have this part of the jquery ui slider script:

```
$("#slider-range_sun").slider({
   range: true,
   min: 0,
   max: 1440,
   step: 15,
   values: [375, 1020],
```

The last line where it says values: [375, 1020] I need to set the numbers with coldfusion variables that are coming from the DB. Putting cfoutput around that line and outputting the variables with pound signs breaks the jquery. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: `Putting cfoutput around that line...breaks the jquery`  That causes a CF error because CF thinks the pound sign in `#slider` is the beginning of a CF variable. When you need a literal pound sign, escape it by using 2 pound signs:  `##slider`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to escape pound character (#) in ColdFusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037766/is-there-a-way-to-escape-pound-character-in-coldfusion)

Comment: Wait a second you are right. I did have a cfoutput around that #slider line. I missed that and it works now after escaping it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, good. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is all just inline JavaScript in a CFM file, you can do this to avoid the jQuery selector entirely:

```
$("#slider-range_sun").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 15,
    values: <cfoutput>[#variableA#, #variableB#]</cfoutput>,
```